# How do I upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10 running in AndroNix?

Tags: upgrade, android

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 in [AndroNix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=studio.com.techriz.andronix) which let you to run Linux without computer. How do I upgrade Ubuntu running in that to 19.10?

Comment: You don't need to upgrade, you need to install (and Ubuntu 19.10 is a bad choice, a good example would be Ubuntu Touch)

Comment: Ubuntu and Android are two independent OS. What do you mean mean by "upgrade my to Ubuntu 19.10 on My Android?"? Please [edit] your question and clarify what you exactly you are looking for.

Comment: I will look into Ubuntu Touch thank you!!  Ubuntu has released 19.10. was interested in upgrading to it on my Android. I have BOTH Android 9.0.and Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 19.04 without a computer. I did it with a app called Andronix.

Comment: I rewrote your question including comments and making it clear. I didn't hear about AndroNix before :D

Comment: On a side note: Ubuntu Touch is a complete different thing. It's an **OS** while what you are using is an OS inside app. I'm not sure what exactly it is, but it seems it's like a Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.andronix.tech/#can-we-install-multiple-linux-systems-on-your-device  specifies you can have multiple Linux distros on the same machine, so in lieu of an upgrade, suggest you install the new version and see if it works AOK. If not, then use their [Post-to-Wall link and ask for advice](https://andronix.app/post/) from experienced users and/or write to the developers at https://andronix.app/contact-us/ .